# Why does baked position pass look different than connecting position to base color?

Tags: texture-baking, baking

When baking a position pass with Bake Type = Position, the position looks binary - each color channel is either completely white or completely black, with no gradient between them. Here is how it looks like on the default cube:
[image: Baked position pass]

When connecting Geometry -> Position to the shader, and baking the Diffuse pass, I get something else, which is what I would expect when baking the position:
[image: Connecting Geometry->Position to the shader]

[image: Baked diffuse pass]

What am I missing, and how do I make the position pass look like the second image?

Comment: Cannot reproduce your problem with bake of position.  Can you provide file?  Want to see bake settings, image settings.  In meantime, simple workaround: plug position into output, bake emission, same as baking any arbitrary value (not really sure why position bakes were even implemented like this, this is a road that ends in sadness when we have forty screens of bake types....)

Comment: I have a workaround (baking the base color as diffuse, or emission as you suggested), was just trying to understand why Bake Type = Position isn't working for me. I need to do this with scripting and using the Position type will be a bit simpler than creating the shading network, if it worked. I start from the default scene with the cube, add an Image texture node with a new image (tried with float32 and without), and use the Cycles Bake menu with "Position".

Comment: My reproduction was make a cube, set bake type to position, put a 32 bit non-color image node in the material, and bake.  And I got your last image, not your first image.